# Is this a reasonable and idiomatic GoLang circular shift implementation?

Tags: go

Can anyone comment on whether this is a reasonable and idiomatic way of implementing [circular shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) of integer arrays in Go? (I deliberately chose not to use bitwise operations.)

How could it be improved?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
    fmt.Println(a)
    rotateR(a, 5)
    fmt.Println(a)
    rotateL(a, 5)
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func rotateL(a []int, i int) {
    for count := 1; count <= i; count++ {
        tmp := a[0]
        for n := 1;n < len(a);n++ {
            a[n-1] = a[n]
        }
        a[len(a)-1] = tmp
    }
}

func rotateR(a []int, i int) {
    for count := 1; count <= i; count++ {
        tmp := a[len(a)-1]
        for n := len(a)-2;n >=0 ;n-- {
            a[n+1] = a[n]
        }
        a[0] = tmp
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems fine and idiomatic to me. Only thing I think would be better would be to make sure that if i is larger than len(a), then you don't rotate more than necessary.

Comment: If you don't mind allocating a temporary array of `i` elements, it might be quicker to just do a few `copy()` operations.  It handles overlapping source and destination correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Rotating the slice one position at a time, and repeating to get the total desired rotation means it will take time proportional to *rotation distance* × *length of slice*. By moving each element directly into its final position you can do this in time proportional to just the length of the slice.

[The code for this](https://play.golang.org/p/UwrHJYskNS) is a little more tricky than you have, and you’ll need a GCD function to determine how many times to go through the slice:

```
func gcd(a, b int) int {
    for b != 0 {
        a, b = b, a % b
    }

    return a
}

func rotateL(a []int, i int) {

    // Ensure the shift amount is less than the length of the array,
    // and that it is positive.
    i = i % len(a)
    if i < 0 {
        i += len(a)
    }

    for c := 0; c < gcd(i, len(a)); c++ {

        t := a[c]

        j := c

        for {
            k := j + i
            // loop around if we go past the end of the slice
            if k >= len(a) {
                k -= len(a)
            }
            // end when we get to where we started
            if k == c {
                break
            }
            // move the element directly into its final position
            a[j] = a[k]
            j = k
        }

        a[j] = t
    }
}
```

Rotating a slice of size *l* right by *p* positions is equivalent to rotating it *left* by *l* − *p* positions, so you can simplify your `rotateR` function by using `rotateL`:

```
func rotateR(a []int, i int) {
    rotateL(a, len(a) - i)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine for in-place modification.

Don't clearly understand what you mean by bitwise operations. Maybe this

```
package main

    import "fmt"

    func main() {
        a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
        fmt.Println(a)
        rotateR(&a, 4)
        fmt.Println(a)
        rotateL(&a, 4)
        fmt.Println(a)
    }

    func rotateL(a *[]int, i int) {
        x, b := (*a)[:i], (*a)[i:]
        *a = append(b, x...)
    }

    func rotateR(a *[]int, i int) {
        x, b := (*a)[:(len(*a)-i)], (*a)[(len(*a)-i):]
        *a = append(b, x...)
    }
```

Code works https://play.golang.org/p/0VtiRFQVl7

It's called reslicing in Go vocabulary. Tradeoff is coping and looping in your snippet vs dynamic allocation in this. It's your choice, but in case of shifting 10000 elements array by one position reslicing looks much cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

I like Uvelichitel solution but if you would like modular arithmetic which would be O(n) complexity

```
package main
func main(){
   s := []string{"1", "2", "3"}
   rot := 5
   fmt.Println("Before RotL", s)
   fmt.Println("After RotL", rotL(rot, s))
   fmt.Println("Before RotR", s)
   fmt.Println("After RotR", rotR(rot,s))

}
func rotL(m int, arr []string) []string{
     newArr := make([]string, len(arr))

     for i, k := range arr{
         newPos := (((i - m) % len(arr)) + len(arr)) % len(arr)
         newArr[newPos] = k
     }

     return newArr
}

func rotR(m int, arr []string) []string{

     newArr := make([]string, len(arr))

     for i, k := range arr{
         newPos := (i + m) % len(arr)
         newArr[newPos] = k
      }
      return newArr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enter multiple values, whatever you want (upd code Uvelichitel)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var N, n int
    fmt.Scan(&N)
    a := make([]int, N)
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        fmt.Scan(&a[i])
    }
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    if n > 0 {
        rotateR(&a, n%len(a))
    } else {
        rotateL(&a, (n*-1)%len(a))
    }
    for _, elem := range a {
        fmt.Print(elem, " ")
    }
}

func rotateL(a *[]int, i int) {
    x, b := (*a)[:i], (*a)[i:]
    *a = append(b, x...)
}

func rotateR(a *[]int, i int) {
    x, b := (*a)[:(len(*a)-i)], (*a)[(len(*a)-i):]
    *a = append(b, x...)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).